# Serviceprincipal template for Azure Datalake analytics in datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-usql-activity

there is a template for using Azure Datalake analytics in azure datafactory with service principal (instead of authorizing manually for each use).

the template looks like this:

```
{
"name": "AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
    "typeProperties": {
        "accountName": "adftestaccount",
        "dataLakeAnalyticsUri": "azuredatalakeanalytics.net",
        "servicePrincipalId": "<service principal id>",
        "servicePrincipalKey": "<service principal key>",
        "tenant": "<tenant info, e.g. microsoft.onmicrosoft.com>",
        "subscriptionId": "<optional, subscription id of ADLA>",
        "resourceGroupName": "<optional, resource group name of ADLA>"
    }
}
```

}

This template does not work in azure data factory, it insists that for the type
"AzureDataLakeAnalytics", it is not possible to have "serviceprincipalid" and it still requires "authorization" as a property.

my question is:
what is the correct json template for configuring a AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService with a serviceprincipal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for asking a question that i figured out myself in the end.

While it is true that the azure portal complains about the template it does allow you deploy it. I had of course tried this, but since the azure portal does not show the error message, only an error flag, i did not realize the error was from the service principals lack of permission and not from the template it complained about.

So by adding more permissions to the service principal and deploying the json, disregarding the compiler complaints. It did work. Sorry for bothering.